# how to save print(i/j) to an output file?

Tags: r

I did simple loop and got the result in print but not sure how to output it.

This is what I coded:

```
>for (i in 0:45) for (j in 0:45) print(i/j)
[1] Inf
[1] 1
[1] 0.5
[1] 0.3333333
[1] 0.25
[1] 0.2
[1] 0.1666667
[1] 0.1428571
[1] 0.125
[1] 0.1111111
[1] 0.1
```

From here, how can i save this outcome? Should I make print (i/j) into an object or is there other way to save it into a file?
thank you,

Comment: there's bunch of places were you can save it too.. from .Rdata (saving the whole workspace) to saving single objects to files you can do pretty much everything. type ?write.table, ?read.table, ?sink or something like that to get started... an read same very introductory R tutorial. Choose any.. your problem will be covered in the first pages probably.

Answer (score 15):

A couple of options, depending on what *output* you want.

1) `capture.output()` will grab the output of the loop into a file:

```
capture.output(for (i in 0:45) for (j in 0:45) print(i/j),
               file = "foo.txt")
```

2) if you want the numbers, then save the `i/j` either as an R object via `save()` or as a text file (e.g. csv) via `write.csv()`, don't print it.

```
out <- c() ## NEVER write a loop like this! Always allocate storage & fill in
for(i in 0:45)
    for(j in 0:45)
        out <- c(out, i/j)
head(out)
save(out, "foo.rda")
write.csv(out, "foo.csv")
```

However, you need to learn about vectorising operations in R. The sort of operation you are doing in R via two loops can be conducted more efficiently in this case using:

```
out2 <- outer(0:45, 0:45, "/")
```

Comment: Thanks Gavin for your answer. Your explanation really is good to understand. I learned a lot from you today.

Answer (score 4):

It really depends on what your want to do. If you just want to capture output into a text file then one of `capture.output`, `cat`,  or `sink` are the functions to look at. If you what to create an R object for later use in a session, then create an object with the desired structure: vector, list, matrix, or data.frame. Objects are then saved with the `save` function. Text representations of objects can be created with `dput` or `dump`.

Answer (score 1):

I just happen to have a function opened that writes to a file. I used sink() (see DWin's and Gavin's answer for other solutions)

```
sink(file = file.name, type = "output")
cat("/* File created on", date(), "*/\n")
cat("/* Walker density:", walk.dens, "*/\n")
cat("/* Capture history has", nchar(as.character(cap.hist[1,])),
        "sessions and", nrow(cap.hist), "walkers", "*/\n")
cat("/* number of initial walkers:", params$num.walker, "*/\n")
cat("/* number of steps per walker:", params$n.steps, "*/\n")
cat("/* area size:", params$area, "*/\n")
cat("/* home range:", params$home.range, "*/\n")
cat("/* number of bins:", params$num.bins, "*/\n")
cat("/* capture probability:", params$prob, "*/\n")
cat("/* number of sessions:", params$sessions, "*/\n")
cat("/* number of bootstraps:", params$num.boots, "*/\n")
cat("/* number of facies:", params$n.faces, "*/\n")
cat("/* working directory:", params$work.dir, "*/\n")
cat("/* number of cores for parallel:", params$num.cores, "*/\n")
cat("/* resolution of raster:", params$rsln, "*/\n")
cat("/* function used to modify resolution:", params$rsln.fun, "*/\n")
cat("/* created walk saved:", params$write.walk, "*/\n")
cat("/* columns: cap.hist/probs/world */\n\n")
apply(mat, 1, function(x) {
            cat(x["cap.hist"], x["probs"], x["supop"], ";", "\n")
        })
sink()
```

Which produces a file (this is only the head):

```
/* File created on Fri Feb 25 15:02:27 2011 */
/* Walker density: 0.001 */
/* Capture history has 40 entries and 67 number of walkers */
/* number of initial walkers: 200 */
/* number of steps per walker: 100 */
/* area size: 500 */
/* home range: 100 */
/* number of bins: 10 */
/* capture probability: 0.2 */
/* number of sessions: 40 */
/* number of lines per segment: */
/* number of bootstraps: 999 */
/* number of facies: 30 */
/* working directory: q:/walker/layers */
/* calculations done in parallel: */
/* number of cores for parallel: 4 */
/* resolution of raster: 5 */
/* function used to modify resolution: */
/* created walk saved: TRUE */
/* columns: cap.hist/probs/world */

1000000000010000100000000000000100000101 0.10876344 1 ; 
1000010000000010011000000000001000010000 0.09428192 1 ; 
0010000000001000001001101100000010000010 0.06079921 1 ; 
0000101000000000000000000000000000001001 0.05272485 1 ; 
1000000001101000001000000001000100000010 0.08599779 1 ;
```

Comment: Thanks Roman for all the cat and sink functions. Now I can try these, which they were new to me.