# Save all print outputs in R

Tags: r, excel

How can I save all print output into excel file. My output file as in matrix form. I have used `write.table()`/`write.matrix()` and `write.xls()`, but it didn't work. `f()` is some function which is used to take outputs. Sample of my output is given as image.

```
for(j in c(10,20)){
  for(i in 1:3){
    b <- print(f(j,i))
    write.table(b,file="aa.xls",sep="\t", col.names = F, row.names = F)
  }
}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Did you try to look at the function `sink`?

Comment: yes. I have tried that one also. but it didn't work.

Comment: Did you see this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5119564/how-to-save-printi-j-to-an-output-file?rq=1

Comment: yes. I saw  that. it only works for the vectors. I tried by using this code. It only save one column of my matrix.

Comment: Can you convert it to a dataframe? They can be easily saved to excel.

Comment: That is the problem. when I run this code, it shows different result within the "for" loop. So, I need all those output. If there is a method to store different data frames when it runs "for" loop, it can be do easily. but after running this  code it will show only one matrix and save it only when using data frames. But at the print() function it shows all the outputs.

Comment: (1) We would need to see the structure of the object returned by `f`. (2) Are you sure you want to be assigning and then writing out the `print`ed object to `b`? (if `f` returns a matrix/data.frame then you should probably remove `print`) (3) You end up with one object because you are overwriting `b` each time through the loop.

Comment: Have you tried the xlsx package?

Comment: yes, I have tried the xlsx package. It didn't success my needs.