# How to save the numbers in the printed strings in R

Tags: r

I want to save the number that is printed using the print() function R. For example,
I have a print(bf(X, Y) command that prints a sentence "Estimated value is : 0.5". How to save only the number 0.5 to a txt/excel file? because I have a loop that will print hundreds of that sentence with different numbers and I want to be able to save all the numbers in a file automatically. Thanks!

Comment: Please make a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: How do you want these numbers to be saved? Just a long list of numbers? Any additional information?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to save print(i/j) to an output file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5119564/how-to-save-printi-j-to-an-output-file)

Comment: @MartinGal Yes, I want to save those numbers to be in a long vector. For example, I will create a null vector of length 100. And for each of the 100 loops, I will save only the number to the vector and at the end the vector will be full with the numbers. But to do that, I will need to figure out how to extract only the number 0.5 from the printed sentence.

Comment: A little more context would be helpful. If at all possible, it's cleaner to go "upstream" and extract the number from wherever `bf(X, Y)` is getting it from, rather than operating on the string returned by `bf()` to extract the number. What is the `bf()` function? Is it something you can modify, or create a modified version of, to return a number rather than a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose, your function `bf(X,Y)` returns a string like `"Estimated value is : 0.5". You could use

```r
library(stringr)

as.double(str_extract(bf(X, Y), "\\d+.\\d+"))
```

to extract the number from this string. Assign it to a vector/data.frame and write it into a `.csv`.

With `base R` you could use

```r
as.double(unlist(regmatches(bf(X, Y), gregexpr("\\d+.\\d+", bf(X, Y)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Ben Bolker. Instead of operating on string you should return the number from the function `bf`. You can take the `print` statement outside the function.

For example, if the current state of the function is like this -

```
bf <- function(X, Y) {
  #...some code
  #...some code
  #res <- calculation for res
  print(c("Estimated value is : ", res))
}
```

Change it to -

```
bf <- function(X, Y) {
  #...some code
  #...some code
  #res <- calculation for res
  res
}
```

So you can save the output of the function in a variable (`res <- bf(X, Y)`). If you need the print statement you can add it outside the function.

```
res <- bf(X, Y)
print(c("Estimated value is : ", res))
```

Comment: Thanks! But I couldn't edit the function. It is from another package.